# Could you give me some advices about this structure of the table in db?

Tags: mysql, sql

All.

Now I'm creating design of the mysql table for the website. Below you can see it.
I have 3 tables:

1. **tbl_user** - for users;
2. **tbl_session** - for sessions and
3. **tbl_block** - for block users - it works like this:

   - if `block == 0` you can login,
   - if `block == 1` you can't login: login_number - increment count (default == 1) if user type 3 times wrong password (login_number == 4) it will be block for 1 hour (block will change to "1" and time_blocked will set)
   - if `block == 2` you can't login for other reason.

---

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tbl_user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_user` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `salt` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `info` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `date_created` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tbl_session`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_session` (
  `session_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `data` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `info` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `date_created` DATETIME NULL ,
  `date_expired` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tbl_user_block`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_user_block` (
  `block_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `block` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `login_number` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  `info` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `date_blocked` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`block_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Is it ok? What I need to improve or change?

Comment: You can add [Foreign Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to auto delete records from **tbl_user_block** & **tbl_session** when user deleted from **tbl_user**

Comment: It's good idea, I also thought about this. Thanks.

Comment: Neville K, what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the time it becomes UNBLOCKED instead of the time it gets blocked (simplifies unblocking logic), but what you have supports what you describe.